# can i get the value before or after using sibling with one statement?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Want to get the value before or after using sibling with one statement?

HTML codes

```
<tr><td width="295" align="right" class="bg1"><div class="barBg2"><div class="info" style="width:60%;"></div></div></td><td width="50" align="center" class="bg1">60%</td><td width="110" align="center" class="bg3">半場控球率</td><td width="50" align="center" class="bg1">40%</td><td width="295" align="left" class="bg1"><div class="barBg"><div class="info" style="width:40%;"></div></div></td><iframe id="tmp_downloadhelper_iframe" style="display: none;"></iframe></tr>
```

HTML Display output

60%半場控球率40%

Python code

```
#coding:utf-8
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('url')

texts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="matchData"]/div[5]//tr//td[preceding-sibling::td="半場控球率" and following-sibling::td="半場控球率"]')

print texts
driver.close()
```

Expected output

```
60% 40%
```

Comment: Can you share HTML sample for both cases? Shared URL (at least for me) is inaccessible

Comment: @Mary Url `http://shorturl.at/iksx1` is not getting resolved. Possibly it have changed.

Comment: dears, changed URL, thanks !

Comment: Your expected output is `60% 40%` , I don't see these values in UI.

Comment: dear, exactly xpath in  "//*[@id="matchData"]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[12]/td[2]" and "//*[@id="matchData"]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[12]/td[4]"

Comment: Post the relevant HTML. The URL is not working for me.

Comment: dear, solved, thanks ! @JeffC

Comment: You still need to add the relevant HTML to the question. This is not just to answer your question, it's for future readers so that they can understand what is being asked. Currently there's not enough info in your question for people to understand the question.

Comment: dear, understood, thanks ! @JeffC

Comment: dear, added HTML part, i will do this next time @JeffC thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[preceding-sibling::td="半場控球率" and following-sibling::td="半場控球率"]
```

predicate means that you want to select element with *BOTH preceding AND following sibling with "半場控球率" text content*. If you want to select element that has *either preceding OR following sibling with text "半場控球率"*, you need

```
[preceding-sibling::td="半場控球率" or following-sibling::td="半場控球率"]
```

Also note that in your case `texts`  is the *list of WebElements*. If you want to get text nodes you can try

```
texts = [td.text for td in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[(preceding-sibling::td="半場控球率" or following-sibling::td="半場控球率") and not(div)]')]
```

Comment: dear, it seem no output